# Is submitting a form in javascript significantly faster than server-side submitting?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, asp-classic

I was told that using javascript to submit in either asp or asp.net causes a faster submit. Is this true or is there no significant difference?

Comment: Are you referring to submitting a form versus using javascript to gather the values of the form and using it to submit the data via an Ajax like XHR?

Comment: No. Actually I'm not familiar with that, but the type of submission I am talking about doesn't involve Ajax. Just javascript. Mostly in asp-classic though. I've never tried it in asp.net..but the question applies to both.

Comment: @Eric:  consider tidying the subject and question, its clear from your comments to answers that you want to compare using Javascript with a typical HTML form.  There is nothing "server-side" about the submission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be a slight overhead doing it with Javascript, and it depends on client machine performance.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't think so? Your browser would have the extra overhead of executing your JS (depending on how complicated your JS is) and then submitting the form. I would want to think that submitting a form the classic way is faster than submitting the form using JS.
And, your server side technology should not really matter (asp/asp.net/jsp/whateva)- it is unrelated to JS.

Comment: To whoever it is who voted my answer down: I am not sure why you would down vote my answer, I would think that you would have the presence of mind to leave a comment explaining your argument.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're talking about HTML form submissions from the browser to the server then neither is faster.  Regardless of how a submission is done, the browser must transmit the data from the user's machine to the server.

Comment: You see Bryan I thought that too. But we had two applications that were nearly identical on a mobile device. One submitting with Javascript and the other normally. The javascript submission was faster by about 3 seconds. We've tested it multiple times. But do you think it was because it was on a mobile device?

Comment: @Eric are those two applications submitting the same form with the same amount of data? Have you considered the network latency involved? Your data connection might depend on your network signal?

Comment: @Eric how exactly did you come up with the 3 second measure? How did you measure the difference?

Comment: Yes,I've considered those things but the difference in speed was too large in every test and at different times. However, we tested on two different mobile devices so one signal may have been a little stronger. So good point.

Comment: To prove a point, you could test your applications using a mobile emulator. I remember this emulator that you would run on your computer for J2ME apps. You would load your MIDPs into it and run them, eliminating the data latency factors. (if you were using apps written in J2ME)